# Getting an error on dockerising nest.js application

Tags: docker, nestjs

I am working on a Nest.js application and this is the Dockerfile that we have. When I run this I am getting an error on the `npm run build` step in docker.
This is the build task in package.json.
 `"build": "nest build"`

```
sh: nest: not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! atom-qbuilder-api@0.0.1 build: `nest build`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the atom-qbuilder-api@0.0.1 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Dockerfile

```
# Build
FROM node:8-alpine as builder

COPY package.json /usr/src/atom/package.json
COPY package-lock.json /usr/src/atom/package-lock.json
WORKDIR /usr/src/atom

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install --production --loglevel warn

ARG APPLICATION
ARG BRANCH
ARG BUILD_NUMBER
ARG SHA
ENV NODE_ENV qa
ENV VERSION 1.0.0


## Copy app directory in container and set workdir
COPY . /usr/src/atom

# Build & Test Coverage
RUN set -x \
  && npm run build \
  && echo "{ \"status\": \"Ok\", \"result\": { \"version\": \"$VERSION\", \"branchName\": \"$BRANCH\", \"SHA\": \"$SHA\", \"buildDate\": \"$(date)\", \"buildNumber\": \"$BUILD_NUMBER\", \"environment\": \"$NODE_ENV\" } }" > build.json

# Release
FROM node:8-alpine 

ENV PORT 3000

COPY --from=builder /usr/src/atom/node_modules /usr/src/atom/node_modules
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/atom/dist /usr/src/atom/dist
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/atom/package.json /usr/src/atom/package.json
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/atom/build.json /usr/src/atom/build.json
WORKDIR /usr/src/atom

EXPOSE $PORT
## Run supervisor as foreground process
CMD bash -c "npm run start:prod && /usr/bin/supervisord"
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

`@nestjs/cli` (where the `nest` command comes from) is by default in `devDependencies`. Unless you've modified your deps in `package.json`, running `npm i --production` will not install `@nestjs/cli` which will lead to the error you currently have. You can either use a multi-staged dockerfile or move `@nestjs/cli` to your `dependencies` instead of devDeps.